# Search for records in my db which match/contain certain WHOLE keyword(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I am looking for a way to search for records in my db which match/contain a certain keyword(s). Now these keyword(s) have to be its own word and not part of another word. So if the keyword is "wich", I don't want it to match records with sand"wich" in the title.

The only way I can think of doing this is by using LIKE but I can't even get that to work.

I tried using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes WHERE title LIKE '%$term%'
```

but that matches all records where $term appears anywhere in the title regardless of whether its part of another word or not.

So I thought this might work

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes WHERE title LIKE '% $term %'
```

but this never returns any records.

can anyone see where I'm going wrong? or if there is a better, more suitable function other than LIKE that I should use?

Comment: If you are using `contains` and `go`, why is the question tagged "mysql".  Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: i was of the understanding CONTAINS is a mysql function? but like i said in the question i've not used CONTAINS before so im not sure if it will do what i want? im using mysql :) thanks

Comment: Your second example should work, is `$term` not being evaluated correctly?  `SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes WHERE title LIKE '% soup %'` will do what you expect

Comment: I don't see `CONTAINS()` in a list of mysql string functions:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: ah thats probably why i cant get it to work then if its not in the mysql function list :( i'll edit my question.

Comment: @tom i've tried the second example again and still wont work, i've even tried it with the value of $term instead of the varible but still didnt return any rows?

Comment: hi jens yes you are correct this is very similar to the above, appoligies as i didn't see this when looking,  i think i have the answer from that thread CONCAT('%', @email , '%'); seems to work, can someone briefly explain what concat does? thanks and sorry for the similar thread!

Comment: Concat concatinating string. See [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed as a "duplicate". The question marked as a duplicate is about referencing user-defined variables; this question seems to be about matching "whole words" within a string, using `LIKE` or some other operator or function. I don't see that this question asked about how to reference MySQL user-defined variables within a SQL statement. (MySQL user variables name start with an **`@`** character, not a **`$`** character.)

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to locate rows that had an occurrence of the word `'soup'` contained in the `title` column, which was not part of another word, I could do something like this:

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM tbl_recipies r
 WHERE r.title LIKE 'soup'           
    OR r.title LIKE 'soup %'
    OR r.title LIKE '% soup'
    OR r.title LIKE '% soup %'
```

That checks for a match 1) entire title, 2) as first word in title, 3) as last word in title, 4) as word within the title.

This assumes that "words" within the title are delimited by one or more spaces, not commas, dashes, or periods.

MySQL also has a `REGEXP` function that can perform matches using regular expressions. You would still need to do the same kind of checks.

Another approach would be to use the `FIND_IN_SET` function. To use that, you could replace all space  characters with a comma.

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM tbl_recipes r
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('soup',REPLACE(r.title,' ',','))
```

This approach lends itself to replacing characters other than space with commas; we could also replace dashes with commas, and tabs with commas, and so on, by wrapping the REPLACE expression in other REPLACE expressions.

Comment: thank you that works but i've found a simpler solution is to use CONCAT like so "...LIKE CONCAT('%', $term , '%')" thanks for you answer tho nice to see it can be achieved in multiple ways :)

Comment: @user288669: The expression **`CONCAT('%','soup','%')`** is equivalent to **`'%soup%'`**, so a `LIKE` with either of this is going to return the exact same result set. That's going to match `'soup'` anywhere in title, even within another word. I don't see how the "simpler solution" you found addresses the question you asked.

Comment: for some reason this is removing the aditional spaces in my solution :( there are spaces in my solution which somehow makes it work? check this link for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537516/how-to-use-an-user-variables-in-mysql-like-clause :)

Comment: @user2885559: I'm not understanding what you mean by "removing additional spaces". The question you referenced, OP seems to have been expecting (wrongly) that MySQL would "recognize" a user-defined variable within a string literal. That is, the characters '@foo', MySQL would seen as reference to a user-defined variable named `@foo`. In your question, you referenced `$term`, and that's not a MySQL variable either. The form `CONCAT('%',?,'%')` or `CONCAT('%',:foo,'%')` is used for prepared statements. And `CONCAT('%',@foo,'%')` is for user-defined variables.

Comment: But none of that really has anything to do with matching only whole words only (avoiding matches to partial words.) And `$term` is not a reference to a MySQL user-defined variable. MySQL user-defined variables start with a **`@`** character, not a **`$`** character.

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysql use this Query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes WHERE title like '% soup %'
```

`contains` is not a `mysql` function.

Comment: *"but that matches all records where $term appears anywhere in the title regardless of whether its part of another word or not."* - OP

Comment: your edit doesn't work, i thought that was the obvious answer but it never returns any records, even if i run it in phpMyAdmin nothing is returned, although there are definately records in the db which should be returned.