# Using mysql variable in query to run a like query

Tags: mysql

I am trying this:

```
SET @query1 =  'star';
   SELECT *
   FROM businesses
   WHERE business_name LIKE @query1
```

But i get following error:

> Error Code: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT)
>   and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'

What am I  doing wrong?

Comment: can you please tell your mysql version.

Comment: I have just checked in phpmyadmin and it is working.

Comment: @S.M.Mohiuddin - Server version: 5.5.40-cll

Comment: @AmitGarg - i am trying to use this in phpMyAdmin. It is not working

Comment: [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537516/how-to-use-an-user-variables-in-mysql-like-clause) help you

Comment: @Jaleelnazir - already tried that get same error as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify the collation

```
SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE business_name LIKE @query1 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

For a more permanent fix you need to change the collation of the server to be compatible with the db or viceversa.I dont have much experience in collations so you have do to a bit of reading.

[Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Answer (score 0):

weird.. but  you can convert your table to that charset like:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.businesses  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE mydb.businesses CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```