# c# parameterized query returns no data/ null values

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Using mysql, I am trying to get/set data using parameterized queries, but some of them are returning null, though they working without using parameterized queries. Here are the two I have I had issues with:

This one returns nothing frm the database:

```
// csvFolder looks ridiculous but this is actually way it needs to look like to work
string csvFolder = "C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\fakename\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\csvScanner\\\\\\\\testeappfolder"
MySqlCommand deleteCheck = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE filepath LIKE '%@csvfolder%' AND expired IS NULL", conn);
deleteCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csvfolder", csvFolder);
MySqlDataReader deleteRdr = deleteCheck.ExecuteReader();
```

But, concatenating the value in will work:

```
MySqlCommand deleteCheck = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE filepath LIKE '%" + csvFolder + "%' AND expired IS NULL", conn);
MySqlDataReader deleteRdr = deleteCheck.ExecuteReader();
```

This one returns null from the ExecuteScalar.

```
MySqlCommand getId = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE filepath = '@filepath' ORDER BY expired DESC LIMIT 1", conn);
getId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filepath", deletedPath.Replace(@"\", "\\\\"));
int id = int.Parse(getId.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

But also works fine when concatenating.

I believe it has to be something with what I am passing (paths with \'s that cause various weirdness), but I cannot see exactly what it is. I have many other parameterized queries for paths that work correctly, but these two do not work. Anyone see something like this before

Comment: you don't need the single quotes around parameters.

Comment: For the first query - I do not believe you can use parameters in a LIKE clause, at least not like that. Reference this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8537547/8061994 for how you might be able to do it.

Comment: I tried using Concat with no luck, thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 0):

Because your parameter was within a quoted part of your query, it doesn't get treated like a parameter, It is treated as a literal string that you are searching for. You need to concatenate it like this...

```
MySqlCommand deleteCheck = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE filepath LIKE '%'+@csvfolder+'%' AND expired IS NULL", conn);
```

Similar in the `ExecuteScalar` example:

```
MySqlCommand getId = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE filepath = @filepath ORDER BY expired DESC LIMIT 1", conn);
```

Other tips:

1. `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block.
2. You can use literal string to make the string a *little* easier to follow: `string csvFolder = @"C:\\\\Users\\\\fakename\\\\Desktop\\\\csvScanner\\\\testeappfolder"` (this still doesn't look right, but it's equivalent to the value you've given).
3. You may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).
4. `SELECT *` with `ExecuteScalar` (which only used the first value from the first row) is at risk of breaking in future: safer to select the particular column you are intending to work with.
5. You're using `LIKE` to look for a value *containing* your parameter when the value would appear to be a rooted path. If the value will *start with* that value, drop the initial wildcard.

Comment: Both answers returned null :(

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"returned null"* since the first query is a DataReader and the second is being put in a not nullable `int`. And for the second, can you confirm that the `Replace` is not interfering with your expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into refactoring my code