# How do I get rid of a syntax error when using a + during the use of LIKE in MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, variables, count

I have an issue with my SQL code. I am trying to count the rows in one table and then post the result along with the remaining variables in a different table. The LIKE statement seems to not work. Everywhere I look I see that I am supposed to do it like the picture without brackets, but sql refuses to let me run it and gives me some syntax error I don't understand. Then I tried it with brackets and it just completely ignore what is inside the brackers it seems like. It just posts 0 as the answer even though it's supposed to be 9. If someone could be of help that would be nice.
[Code without brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4icJ.png)
[Code with brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIUPG.png)

Comment: Do not post code as image, but edit your question and add it as text. Try and use  `tweet_text LIKE CONCAT('%', @weg, '%'); `. The same for `datum` . Check for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537516/how-to-use-an-user-variables-in-mysql-like-clause

Comment: Thank you this worked! I will copy paste my code from now on!